Unable to configure vercel dns with resend
I am a beginner with resend.
I am trying to configure the resend custom domain with the pre-hosted next.js project to send email in vercel. I have added the DNS record copied from the resend and past it in the vercel Domains and then tried to configure the resend domain in resend but every time I got failure. The status is going to be in failure every time I try to configure. I have also created multiple domain and try the same process but not work for me.
Vercel DNS Record 
Debugging Image
I have tried to get support from the internet but no one is getting satified.
Steps I have followed:
1. Create a resend API Key
2. Add API key in nextjs project
3. Create custom domain in vercel
4. Add TXT and MX record in DNS record in Domain section on Vercel.
5. Press the verified button in resend custom domain

After 2 days the status is changed to failure from pending.
I am trying to solve this problem from 1 weeks 



I don't think Vercel will allow you to send emails using their sub-domain. What you are trying to achieve having Resend verify a domain which you don't own. You most probably need your own domain, point CNAME on the Vercel app and then continue with the TXT verification for Resend

Thank's for the response. Should I alter the CNAME in vercel sub domain section or Add new record .  Is there any way to create/use domain in free for vercel

Not sure about the free domain part, but what you should do if you have a domain is that you create CNAME record from your DNS provider that point to the subdomain provided by Vercel. Then configure the mailing with MX and TXT records for verification
